# change bootstrap label depend on words from mysql row

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, label, row

I do have some problems with my code.

I would like to change the color on my lables if it goes from one status to another depending on the world from mysql db.

First of all, I have the code:

```
<table class="table responsive">
                     <div id="employee_table">  
                          <table class="table">  
                               <tr>  
                                   <th width="10%">ARK ID</th>
                                   <th width="20%">User</th>
                                    <th width="45%">Header</th>
                                   <th width="10%">Status</th>
                                    <th width="20%">Priority</th>

                               </tr>  
                               <?php  
                               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                               {  
                               ?>  
                               <tr>  
                                   <td><?php echo $row["ark_id"]; ?></td> 
                                   <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td> 
                                   <td><a href="read.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row["overskrift"]; ?></td>  
                                   <td><?php echo $row["prioritet"]; ?></td> 
                                   <td><?php echo $row["status"]; ?></td>  

                                    </tr>  
                               <?php  
                               }  
                               ?>  
                          </table>
```

Second of all, I'll have Status and priority to change label color like this
If priority is LOW then Green Label
If priority is MEDIUM then Blue
if priority is HIGH then RED

... The same function to the Status Pending .... And so on..

I hope someone could help me :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope below code help you

```
<table class="table responsive">
    <div id="employee_table">  
        <table class="table">  
            <tr>  
               <th width="10%">ARK ID</th>
               <th width="20%">User</th>
               <th width="45%">Header</th>
               <th width="10%">Status</th>
               <th width="20%">Priority</th>
            </tr>  
            <?php  
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
            {  
                if($row["prioritet"] == "LOW") {
                   $priority_color = '#009933'; // low priority color
                }  
                else if($row["prioritet"] == "MEDIUM") {
                    $priority_color = '#0099ff'; // Medium priority color
                }  
                else if($row["prioritet"] == "HIGH"){
                    $priority_color = '#ff0000'; // High priority color
                }else{
                     $priority_color = '#ffffff'; // default color
                }
            ?>  
            <tr>  
                <td><?php echo $row["ark_id"]; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td> 
                <td><a href="read.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row["overskrift"]; ?></td>  
                 <td><?php echo $row["prioritet"]; ?></td> 
                 <td  bgcolor="<?php echo $priority_color; ?>"><?php echo $row["status"]; ?></td>  
            </tr>  
            <?php  
            }  
            ?>  
</table>
```

Comment: I was missing some lines, sorry! :) It's all good now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry for taking your time, but I was missing some code - The other part of my code the "Status" wasn't into this code, how to do a IF sentence more?

Comment: Please explain more about your question so we can help you.

Comment: I've got two <td> rows One with status and One with priority both should change depending on the Word in their row in MySQL

Comment: what's your status value?

Comment: <td><?php echo $row["prioritet"]; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $row["status"]; ?></td>  

That's my two <td>'s - I would cgange colors on both, like the first example  you wrote me.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the priority on the beginning of the while loop:

```
<table class="table responsive">
    <div id="employee_table">  
        <table class="table">  
            <tr>  
               <th width="10%">ARK ID</th>
               <th width="20%">User</th>
               <th width="45%">Header</th>
               <th width="10%">Status</th>
               <th width="20%">Priority</th>
            </tr>  
            <?php  
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
            {  
                if($row["prioritet"] == "LOW") {
                   $color = '#000000'; // choose color
                }  
                else if($row["prioritet"] == "MEDIUM") {
                   $color = '#888888'; // choose color
                }  
                else {
                   $color = '#ffffff'; // choose color
                }
            ?>  
            <tr>  
                <td><?php echo $row["ark_id"]; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td> 
                <td><a href="read.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row["overskrift"]; ?></td>  
                 <td style="color:<?php echo $color?>"><?php echo $row["prioritet"]; ?></td> 
                 <td style="color:<?php echo $color?>"><?php echo $row["status"]; ?></td>  
            </tr>  
            <?php  
            }  
            ?>  
</table>
```